# Reply to block chain in smart card for T=1

Tags: smartcard, chaining, blockchain

The is a question related to T=1 protocol for smartcard. The scenario is as follows: The interface device has to send, say 5 chained I-blocks to the card. So the M-bit is set for the first four blocks and cleared for the last one.

Can the card, say during the transfer of 2nd I-Block send an IFS or WTX request as response? OR the card MUST reply with R-blocks always for chained I-Blocks.

Regards,
Jain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO 7816-3, section 11.6.2.2 Chaining, appears clear to me in that respect:

You have to sent (ISO-speak **shall**) a R-block with either positive or negative acknowledge.

It's neither a sensible time for an IFS (field size negotiation must have happend before, otherwise the terminal would not know, at which position to chain), nor a WTX (card processing only starts after the complete APDU has been received).

Comment: It is interesting that under T=CL as defined in ISO 14443-4: "The PICC is allowed to send an S(WTX) block instead of an I-block or an R(ACK) block."...As far as I understand the latter case (i.e. when the S(WTX) is sent instead of R(ACK)) happens during the chaining...

Comment: Additionally the Rule 3 at section 11.6.2.3 of ISO 7816-3 talks about the previously received I-block -- which might be any I-block (even a chained one)...I wonder what the correct explanation is